# User defined array sizes with multiple inputs

Tags: java

I am working on my final and I got to the part I an mildly confused about.

1. I can't figure out if it's possible to call the Admin or Student inputs with it being outside of the if statement. I need to call the results in the 3rd and 4th option in the menu and I can't do it without it throwing errors.

   ```
       public class MainEntry {

       static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           int printMenu = 0;

           while(printMenu != 5){

               printMenu();
               printMenu = console.nextInt();

               if (printMenu == 1){

                   String firstName;
                   String lastName;
                   int year;
                   double[] grades;
                   double studentId;
                   String major;

                   int size;
                   System.out.println("How many students do you have? ");
                   size = console.nextInt();

                   Student newStudent = new Student();


                       int[] stud = new int[size];

                        for(int i = 0; i < stud.length; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("What is the students first name? ");
                            firstName = console.next();
                            newStudent.setFirstName(firstName);

                            System.out.println("What is the students last name? ");
                            lastName = console.next();
                            newStudent.setLastName(lastName);

                            System.out.println("What year are they in? ");
                            year = console.nextInt();
                            newStudent.setYear(year);
                                                    System.out.println("Enter in their grades: ");
       grades = console.nextDouble();newStudent.setGrades(grades);

                            System.out.println("What is their Student ID number? ");
                            studentId = console.nextDouble();
                            newStudent.setStudentID(studentId);

                            System.out.println("What is the student's major? ");
                            major = console.next();
                            newStudent.setMajor(major);

                        }


               }

               else if (printMenu == 2){
                   Admin newAdmin = new Admin();


                   System.out.println("How many admins do you have? ");
                    int size = console.nextInt();
                    int[] admins = new int[size];

                    for(int i = 0; i < admins.length; i++)

                    {                   
                        System.out.println("What is the admin's first name? ");
                        String firstName = console.next();
                        newAdmin.setFirstName(firstName);

                        System.out.println("What is the admin's last name? ");
                        String lastName = console.next();
                        newAdmin.setLastName(lastName);

                        System.out.println("What is their Admin's ID number? ");
                        double adminId = console.nextDouble();
                        newAdmin.setAdminId(adminId);

                        System.out.println("What is the Admin's department? ");
                        String department = console.next();
                        newAdmin.setDepartment(department);

                        System.out.println("What is their salary? ");
                        int salary = console.nextInt();
                        newAdmin.setsalary(salary);


                    }
               }

           else if (printMenu == 3){

       System.out.println("First name: " + newStudent.getFirstName());
       System.out.println("Last name: " + newStudent.getLastName());
           System.out.println("ID Number: " + newStudent.getStudentID());System.out.println("GPA: " + newStudent.getgrade());System.out.println("Major: "+newStudent.getMajor());                  

        }

               else if (printMenu == 4){



       System.out.println("First name: " + newAdmin.getFirstName());
       System.out.println("Last name: " + newAdmin.getLastName()); System.out.println("ID Number: " + newAdmin.getAdminId()); System.out.println("GPA: " + newAdmin.getgrade());
                   System.out.println("Major: " + newAdmin.getsalary());

               }



               else if(printMenu == 5){
                   System.out.println("Thanks for using my program!");
               }

           }



       }

       // This method will bring up the beginning menu for the user
               public static void printMenu(){

                   //Asking the user which option they are selecting
                           System.out.println("How would you like to input your data?");
                           System.out.println("1. Enter in students. ");
                           System.out.println("2. Enter in admins. ");
                           System.out.println("3. Print the student information. ");
                           System.out.println("4. Print admin information. ");
                           System.out.println("5. Exit the program. ");


               }



   }
   ```
2. For the student grade I need to average there 5 grades together using an array.

   public class Student { 
           // stores the first name
           private String firstName;

   ```
       // stores the last name
       private String lastName;

       // stores the 
       private int year;

       // stores the grades
       private double[] grades;

       // stores the ID number
       private double studentID;

       private String major;

       public static int studentInfo;


       //here is where it sets the defaults
       public Student(){
           firstName = "Jane";
           lastName = "Doe";
           year = 1;
           grades = new double[]{0,0,0,0,0};
           studentID = 0;
           major = "undeclared";

           studentInfo++;
       }



       public static int studentInfo(){
           return (studentInfo);
       }

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName;
       }



       public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
           this.firstName = firstName;
       }



       public String getLastName() {
           return lastName;
       }



       public void setLastName(String lastName) {
           this.lastName = lastName;
       }



       public int getYear() {
           return year;
       }



       public void setYear(int year) {
           this.year = year;
       }



       public double[] getGrades() {
           return grades;
       }



       public void setGrades(double[] grades) {
           this.grades = grades;
       }



       public double getStudentID() {
           return studentID;
       }



       public void setStudentID(double studentID) {
           this.studentID = studentID;
       }



       public String getMajor() {
           return major;
       }



       public void setMajor(String major) {
           this.major = major;
       }



       public static int getStudentInfo() {
           return studentInfo;
       }



       public static void setStudentInfo(int studentInfo) {
           Student.studentInfo = studentInfo;
       }



       public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int year, double[] grades, double studentID){

           this.firstName = firstName;

           this.lastName = lastName;

           this.year = year;

           this.grades = grades;

           this.studentID = studentID;

           studentInfo++;
           }


   }
   ```

I understand how to build it in the class side but I don't understand how to use it in `MainEntry`. It keeps asking me to change type and I can't figure out what else to do to fix it. I have issues with arrays so that's something that I'm not quite the best at...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Just declare your Student and Admin objects out of your statement. 2. Implement a Average(double[] grades) method, in which you loop through your array, suming their values and then dividing the result by the number of grades in the array.

Answer (score 0):

1) For this, you need to declare newStudent outside of the if statement.

```
    while(printMenu != 5){

        Student newStudent = null; // ← newStudent is declared here

        printMenu();
        printMenu = console.nextInt();
```

This means that you don't declare it later, only assign to it the result of the new operator:

```
            int size;
            System.out.println("How many students do you have? ");
            size = console.nextInt();

            newStudent = new Student(); // ← this is only an assignment, not a declaration
```

It also means that you have to be careful when the user wants to display the information concerning the student, because newStudent can be null (i.e. no information have been entered yet).

2) The average is not a double array, just a double. This is why the compiler complains about incompatible types. The average will not be computed automatically, you have to do it yourself. Basically, you need two steps. First, iterate through the array and calculate the sum of the elements:

```
double sum = 0;
for (double g : grades) { // do this for all elements of the array
    sum += g;      // add the element to the sum
}
```

Then, the average is the sum divided by the number of elements.

```
double average = sum / grades.length;
```